# Attempting to display the current time in GMT, PST and EST using the dateTime class

Tags: php, datetime, timezone, format

I have attempted to do this using the following code:

```
$date = new DateTime('now');

$datePST = $date->setTimezone(new DateTimezone('PST'));

$dateEST = $date->setTimezone(new DateTimezone('EST'));

echo $date->format('H:i:s');
echo '<br />';
echo $EST = $dateEST->format('H:i:s');
echo '<br />';
echo $PST = $datePST->format('H:i:s');
```

But they all output the same time. Why are they not outputting the correct times?

Comment: According to [the PHP docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.others.php), you should not use the zones "PST" or "EST. They only exist for backward compatibility reasons.  You should instead use [the supported time zones](http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php), specifically `America/Los_Angeles` or `America/New_York`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because they are all pointing to the same object. So when you change the timezone in one you are changing it for all of them.

```
$date = new DateTime('now');
echo $date->format('H:i:s');
echo '<br />';
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimezone('PST'));
echo $date->format('H:i:s');
echo '<br />';
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimezone('EST'));
echo $date->format('H:i:s');
```

If you want to have separate variables for each timezone you can use `clone` to create new objects:

```
$date = new DateTime('now');
$datePST = clone $date;
$datePST = $datePST->setTimezone(new DateTimezone('PST'));
$dateEST = clone $date;
$dateEST = $dateEST->setTimezone(new DateTimezone('EST'));

echo $date->format('H:i:s');
echo '<br />';
echo $EST = $dateEST->format('H:i:s');
echo '<br />';
echo $PST = $datePST->format('H:i:s');
```

If you're using PHP 5.5 you can use the new [`DateTimeImmutatable()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetimeimmutable.php) class as well:

```
$date = new DateTimeImmutable('now');
$datePST = $date->setTimezone(new DateTimezone('PST'));
$dateEST = $date->setTimezone(new DateTimezone('EST'));
```

FYI, using `"now"` is unnecessary as when no parameter is passed to `DateTime()` it automatically defaults to the current date and time..